# How do I get panda's "update" function to overwrite numbers in one column but not another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Currently, I'm using:

```
csvdata.update(data, overwrite=True)
```

How can I make it update and overwrite a specific column but not another, small but simple question, is there a simple answer?

Comment: You could just pass only that column of `data`, e.g. `csvdata.update(data['col_to_update'], overwrite=True)`. For better answers, it would be good if you could post a small reproducible example of your data.

Comment: That works perfectly, I had made a really hacky work around just after I posted by using `.copy()` and then deleting columns and passing two updates

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than update with the entire DataFrame, just update with the subDataFrame of columns which you are interested in. For example:

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]: 
   A   B
0  1  99
1  3  99
2  5   6

In [12]: df2
Out[12]: 
   A  B
0  a  2
1  b  4
2  c  6

In [13]: df1.update(df2[['B']])  # subset of cols = ['B']

In [14]: df1
Out[14]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
```

Comment: Something that threw me off was that the dtype of my indexes weren't the same, so they matched but the dtypes didn't, and that prevented the update from happening

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it for a single column:

```
import pandas
import numpy
csvdata = pandas.DataFrame({"a":range(12), "b":range(12)})
other = pandas.Series(list("abcdefghijk")+[numpy.nan])

csvdata["a"].update(other)

print csvdata

     a   b
0    a   0
1    b   1
2    c   2
3    d   3
4    e   4
5    f   5
6    g   6
7    h   7
8    i   8
9    j   9
10   k  10
11  11  11
```

or, as long as the column names match, you can do this:

```
other = pandas.DataFrame({"a":list("abcdefghijk")+[numpy.nan], "b":list("abcdefghijk")+[numpy.nan]})
csvdata.update(other["a"])
```